# symfony 5.4 terminal commands, Could not open input file

Tags: php, symfony

I created a new project in symfony 5.4 and I start typing commands in terminal:

- `composer require server --dev`
- `php bin/console make:controller` (I already tried app/console)
- `symfony console make:controller firstController`

I am facing this error:

> Could not open input file: bin/console

Comment: If this is a **new** project: did you install `symfony/console`?

Comment: Somebody voted to close this as "needs debugging details," however, after I edited to introduce formatting, it looks like both the commands that exhibit the problem and the error message are there.